# SQL: count() and group by

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

> Blockquote
>       s1:  (different users use different browser at some time)

```
   browser time
1    opera    1
2    opera    1
3    opera    3
4        d    4
5        d    5
6    opera    6
7    opera    7
8        d    8
9    opera    9
10   opera   10
11       d   11
12       d   12
13       d   13
14       d   14
15   opera   15
```

> Blockquote
>   s2: (the time that the browser opera is used)

```
    opera time
1     1    1
2     1    1
3     1    3
4     1    6
5     1    7
6     1    9
7     1   10
```

I want to find out the number of opera used at different time. (If at time 2, no one use opera, it should have a 0 there.)

> Blockquote

```
Select s1.time, count(s2.opera)
From s1 left join s2 on s1.time=s2.time
Group by s1.time
```

Then I have this:

```
> Blockquote
> dddd
    time        count (s2.opera)
1     1                4
2     3                1
3     4                0
4     5                0
5     6                1
6     7                1
7     8                0
8     9                1
9    10                1
10   11                0
11   12                0
12   13                0
13   14                0
14   15                1
```

Which is not correct, because at time 1, opera should only has 2 counts instead of 4. I don't know where went wrong.

Comment: you need to explain the problem in a clearer way. However by guessing at what you requirements are, you need to look at LEFT OUT JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN. to be able to get 0 where no count is found (Look at functions like COALESCE)

Comment: you can check the desired answer below with complete demo code the code i have written is in oracle sql...

Answer (score 0):

In table 1, you have 2 rows with [opera, 1]. 
In table 2, you have 2 rows with [1, 1].

```
2 * 2 = 4
```

So given your data, 4 is correct, just not what you want.

---

> I want to find out the number of opera used at different time.

That information is entirely contained in table 2.

```
Select s2.time, count(s2.opera)
From s2
Group by s2.time
```

---

> (If at time 2, no one use opera, it should have a 0 there.)

Hard. You don't have a time 2 in either table, so SQL has no way of knowing that you want it. (Think about it. If it just decided to give you [2, 0], then why wouldn't it also give you [999999999, 0].)

Answer (score 0):

@jessie use the below given demo code and query for your desired result as of oracle sql:-

```
create table sd1 (browser varchar2(10), time number)

insert all into sd1 values('opera',1)
into sd1 values('opera',1)
into sd1 values('opera',3)
into sd1 values('d',4)
into sd1 values('d',5)
into sd1 values('opera',6)
into sd1 values('opera',7)
into sd1 values('d',8)
into sd1 values('opera',9)
into sd1 values('opera',10)
into sd1 values('d',11)
into sd1 values('d',12)
into sd1 values('d',13)
into sd1 values('d',14)
into sd1 values('opera',15)
select * from dual;

commit;

 create table sd2 (opera number, time number)

 insert all into sd2 values(1,1)
 into sd2 values(1,1)
 into sd2 values(1,3)
 into sd2 values(1,6)
 into sd2 values(1,7)
 into sd2 values(1,9)
 into sd2 values(1,10)
 select * from dual;

 commit;

SELECT X.TIME ,COUNT(OPERA) OPERA_USED
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM SD1
  ORDER BY 2) X LEFT JOIN SD2
  ON X.TIME=SD2.TIME
  GROUP BY X.TIME
 ORDER BY 1;
```

And the below query will give you all those time which are not inserted into your header sd1 table i.e you said you need time 2 and against to which count to be 0 though time 2 is not there in table sd1 ,result is just based on your given data .

```
select dha.time time,nvl(dh.opera_used,0) opera_used
from
    (
    select x.time ,count(opera) opera_used
    from 
    (
      select distinct * from sd1
      order by 2) x left join sd2
      on x.time=sd2.time 
      group by x.time
    )dh
    right join 
    (
     select level time from
        (
         select max(time) time from sd1
        )
    connect by level<=time
    ) dha
    on dha.time=dh.time
    order by 1;
```